# No decimal places with cl-format (lisp format)

Tags: clojure, string-formatting, clojurescript

I want to create a function that will format a number with exactly as many decimal places as I want. Here's my attempt with `cl-format`:

```
=> (defn f [decimal-places n] (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil (str "~" decimal-places ",0$") n))
#'core/f
=> (f 5 55)
"55.00000"
=> (f 4 55)
"55.0000"
=> (f 3 55)
"55.000"
=> (f 2 55)
"55.00"
=> (f 1 55)
"55.0"
=> (f 0 55)
"55."
```

Notice the last one, with zero decimal places. I'm doing essentially this:

```
=> (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~0,0$" 55)
"55."
```

It has decimal separator - a dot - in there. How do make it render simply "55" (without a dot), in a way that I could easily (like with `str` in my example) make it to work with `decimal-places` greater than 0?

Comment: Not an answer but FYI: You can also write `"~v,0$"` and pass both, `decimal-places` and `n` to `cl-format`

Comment: @ClojureMostly Nice tip, thanks. I almost never use `cl-format`, so this is useful.

Comment: Add a test, when the number of decimal places becomes zero, you print an integer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Although [`cl-format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format) supports branching, in this case I'd stick with a simple `if`, because the arguments of format actually are quite different in both cases:

```
(defn f [decimal-places n]
  (if (zero? decimal-places)
      (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~D" (Math/round n))
      (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~v$" decimal-places n)))
```

I round `n` to the nearest integer instead of just truncating with `(int n)`.

An alternative is to remove any dot character at the end of the formatted string:

```
(defn undot [string]
  (if (clojure.string/ends-with? string ".")
      (subs string 0 (- (count string) 1))
      string))

(defn f [decimal-places n]
  (undot (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~v$" decimal-places n)))
```

Comment: No saner way, really? :/ Also, `zerop` - `(= zerop decimal-places 0)` - a typo?

Comment: @kamituel A typo, yes, thanks a lot. Until `~/` is implemented, this is the most readable way to me.

Comment: I think there's "no saner way" because the intention of the `f` directive is to include a decimal point.  You're trying to use one directive to create two different kinds of representations--one with and one without a decimal point.  (You might know that Peter Seibel's [A Few FORMAT Recipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) is a good resource for `cl-format`, by the way.  Guy Steele's [*Common Lisp the Language* 2nd ed](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/cltl2.html) also has some good material on `format`.)